# Connecting to a split plane in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

I am using Altium 14.0.9. I have a split plane on my inner layer of a 4 layer PCB. This split plane is connected to the net `C6_2`.  It is basically 2 polygons on my bottom layer that are connected to each other via a small split plane on the inner layer.

This can be seen in the image below:

[image]

The split plane on layer `Vcc` is enclosed by the green lines as shown. The 2 polygons can be seen as 2 grey shapes on another layer. I am assigning the split plane the net name `NetC6_2` (as shown).  But still the vias are not connecting to that split plane. As you can see there is an unconnected net connecting the 2 islands (this is shown as a thin white line bridging them 2 islands).

Does anybody know why this does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely: It already did, try to close the PCB document, then re-open it. Run the DRC again.

Less likely: Check your rules, especially your Plane Connect rules

Comment: Also, check your "routing layers" rule

Comment: The Plane Connect rules was the villain. Thank u @Tom L.